# How to find has many records based on search field with OR condition

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have implemented a search which can search records from different columns but it does not work if I search records in has_many (categories) table for category name search using same search field.

I have model like this:

Influencer:

```
has_many :influencer_categories, dependent: :destroy
has_many :categories, through: :influencer_categories
```

The code is:

Controller:

```
@influencers = Influencer.search(params)
```

Model:

```
def self.search(params)
      .includes(:categories)
      .where(search_all(params[:q]))
      .where("LOWER(categories.name) like '%#{params[:q].downcase}%'")
end

def self.search_all(criteria)
    if criteria.include?('@') && criteria.start_with?('@')
      criteria.split(' ').map {|criterion| "LOWER(username) like '%#{criterion.downcase.gsub('@', '')}%'"}.join(' OR ')
    elsif criteria.include?('#') && criteria.start_with?('#')
      criteria.split(' ').map {|criterion| "LOWER(bio) like '%#{criterion.downcase.gsub('#', '')}%'"}.join(' OR ')
    else
      "LOWER(full_name) like '%#{criteria.downcase}%' OR LOWER(username) like '%#{criteria.downcase}%' OR LOWER(bio) like '%#{criteria.downcase}%'"
    end
  end
```

The output error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause 
entry for table "categories"
LINE 1: ... '%food%' OR LOWER(bio) like '%food%') AND (LOWER(categories...

                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "influencers" WHERE (LOWER(full_name) like '%food%' OR 
LOWER(username) like '%food%' OR LOWER(bio) like '%food%') AND 
(LOWER(categories.name) like '%food%')):
```

Perhaps I need to include **OR** in my condition to get the desired results so for **food** category, all influencers having **food** category shows up. 
Thats what I need to do.

I believe something like this will work:

```
SELECT "influencers"."id" FROM "influencers" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"influencer_categories" ON "influencer_categories"."influencer_id" = 
"influencers"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = 
"influencer_categories"."category_id" WHERE (LOWER(full_name) like '%food%' OR 
LOWER(username) like '%food%' OR LOWER(bio) like '%food%' OR 
LOWER(categories.name) like '%food%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, below query worked well with me:**

I needed to concatenate the has_many part in the end or my first part of query.

Also `references` is also needed to avoid errors.

```
def self.search(params)
   .includes(:categories)
   .where(search_all(params[:q])+" OR LOWER(categories.name) like 
'%#{params[:q].downcase}%'")
   .references(:categories)
end
```

**That outputs the following SQL Query:**

```
SELECT "influencers"."id" AS t0_r0, "influencers"."instagram_id" AS t0_r1, 
"influencers"."full_name" AS t0_r2, "influencers"."username" AS t0_r3, 
"influencers"."profile_picture" AS t0_r4, "influencers"."website" AS t0_r5, 
"influencers"."bio" AS t0_r6, "influencers"."created_at" AS t0_r7, 
"influencers"."updated_at" AS t0_r8, "influencers"."slug" AS t0_r9, 
"influencers"."email" AS t0_r10, "influencers"."follower_count" AS t0_r11, 
"influencers"."like_count" AS t0_r12, "influencers"."comment_count" AS t0_r13, 
"influencers"."media_count" AS t0_r14, "influencers"."country" AS t0_r15, 
"influencers"."state" AS t0_r16, "influencers"."city" AS t0_r17, 
"categories"."id" AS t1_r0, "categories"."name" AS t1_r1, 
"categories"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "categories"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM 
"influencers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "influencer_categories" ON 
"influencer_categories"."influencer_id" = "influencers"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"categories" ON "categories"."id" = "influencer_categories"."category_id" 
WHERE (LOWER(full_name) like '%food%' OR LOWER(username) like '%food%' OR 
LOWER(bio) like '%food%' OR LOWER(categories.name) like '%food%') AND 
"influencers"."id" IN (188, 189)
```

If that could be done with more elegant way, please add your answers or comments.